# adding and accessing controllers in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controllers

If I have a controller, how do I access it via URL with newly added methods?

Reason I am confused is because I have a route,

```
map.connect 'assignments/:external_id.:format', :controller => "assignments", :action => "show", :external_id => /\d{6}/
```

It seems that I can't access any other method within the `assignments` controller because if i do

```
mysite.com/assignments/other_method
```

It'll assume that other_method is an ID I'm passing into the `show` controller, as specified in the route entry above.

Edit:

I added this to the top:

```
map.connect 'assignments/send/', :controller => "assignments", :action => "send"
```

and am now getting this error:

```
ArgumentError in AssignmentsController#show
```

The route for `assignments/send` is the first declration for any of the assignments controller

Comment: I think you might be missing a required argument after 'assignments/send/', perhaps 'assignments/send/:id' would work? It almost surely should be ending with a variable of some sort to select the assignment model?

Comment: i am not using a model in this case, to be more specific i'm taking some values from a form and generating emails from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routing table should have it in this order

```
map.connect 'assignments/:external_id.:format', :controller => "assignments", :action => "show", :external_id => /\d{6}/

map.connect 'assignments/send/', :controller => "assignments", :action => "send"
```

to end with

```
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

as your most general case.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the right route pattern for that second case and make sure you keep in mind that the mappings are evaluated from top to bottom (first match gets executed).

Comment: so the most "vague" of routes should be placed at the bottom?

Comment: exactly, usually that being just the map.resources :controller